# Emscripten and em++ install question

Tags: command-line, package-management, bash, paths, desktop-directories

I installed the latest emsdk_portable so I could use Emscripten, then I ran the following commands with no problem.

```
$ ./emsdk update
$ ./emsdk install latest
```

Then, I went to run this command:

```
./emsdk activate latest
```

and [this was the output](http://pastebin.com/AemA68Rb), my question is with this line in that output:

> To conveniently access the selected set of tools from the command line, consider adding the following directories to PATH, or call 'source ./emsdk_sh' to do this for you.

However, there is no "emsdk_sh" file in the emsdk_portable folder. So I'm not sure what to do.

How can I add these directories to the PATH?

The intended goal of all this is because I ran into an error saying /em++: Command not found, I'm hoping adding these paths will resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file and see if it works:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/bryce/Downloads/emsdk_portable:/home/bryce/Downloads/emsdk_portable/clang/fastcomp/build_master_64/bin:/home/bryce/Downloads/emsdk_portable/node"
```

*Note: I'm just basing this off of the output you have linked on Pastebin. I have **not** tried installing the software myself.*

Comment: this seems to have worked, unfortunately it didn't solve my /em++ problem though. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryce Have you tried running `emcc` from the terminal. Just to check that it works - `emcc -v` ? [source link](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#verifying-emscripten)